# True or False: No Parametrized Surface is Closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Is no parametrized surface (topologically) closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$? I use the [definition of Fitzpatrick's *Advanced Calculus* (2009)](https://books.google.com/books?id=4hhFXPdTXwoC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA533#v=onepage&q&f=false). So far, all the examples I've seen have not been closed -- for example, $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=1,z>0\}$ or $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=z^2,z>0,(x-1)^2+y^2<1\}.$

Comment: You should include the definition, since it seems very non-standard (why should we exclude $\{ z=0 \}$?).

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz the definition can be seen in the link from which you will see that only $C^1$ maps with bounded derivatives on boundes open sets are considered. This implies that a parametrized surface in this sense is a bounded set itself.

Comment: Does $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, \sin x + \cos y)$ on $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ works?

Comment: @AlexVong, $[0,1]^2$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a $C^2$ curve $\alpha : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R^2}$ having the following shape:

$\hspace{10.5em}$[image: 1]

Then write $\alpha(t) = (\alpha_1(t), \alpha_2(t))$ and define $\mathbf{r} : \mathcal{R} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2 < 1\} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by

$$ \mathbf{r}(x, y) = \left( \frac{\alpha_1(r)}{r}x, \frac{\alpha_1(r)}{r}y, \alpha_2(r) \right), \qquad r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}. \tag{*} $$

The only point where $\mathbf{r}$ may fail to be regular is the origin, but the regularity of $\alpha_1$ guarantees that $\mathbf{r}$ is indeed $C^1$ on all of $\mathcal{R}$. Now its graph looks like

$\hspace{3.3em}$[image: 2]

Although the surface seems self-intersecting, the parametrization is in fact one-to-one since $\alpha$ is one-to-one on $[0, 1)$.

Moreover, it is clear from the graph that $\mathcal{S} = \mathbf{r}(\mathcal{R})$ is topologically closed. Of course one can give a proof: Extend $\mathbf{r}$ to all of $\bar{\mathcal{R}} = \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ by using the formula $\text{(*)}$. Then we have $\mathcal{S} = \mathbf{r}(\bar{\mathcal{R}}) $ since $\alpha(1) = \alpha(t_0)$ for some $t_0 \in [0, 1)$. Now $\mathcal{S}$ is an image of the compact set $\bar{\mathcal{R}}$ under a continuous map, it is compact and hence closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Something I can't wrap my head around -- why do we divide by $r$ in formula $(*)$? I get that $x/r=\cos\theta$ and $y/r=\sin\theta$ and I have verified empirically that using $(\alpha_1(r)x,\alpha_1(r)y,\alpha_2(r))$ does not work, but I don't see why. Secondly, how could I come up with  examples like this on my own? I see that it works, but I have no idea how people can come up with such seemingly intricate examples.

Comment: @xFioraMstr18, As you correctly guessed, the factor $1/r$ is required to produce $(x/r, y/r) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, which amounts to rotating the curve around the $z$-axis. Next, the idea was to compensate the 'missing boundary' of $\mathcal{S}$ by attaching the surface to itself, for otherwise this missing boundary will make $\mathcal{S}$ fail to be closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$.